# Mass move of reports to a new or different folder

Tags: reporting

I Created a report to show all the reports not run in last 6 months and not part of any dashboard, report has returned about 700 reports. I want to move these 700 reports to Quarantine folder before I delete them from the system. How can I move them to Quarantine folder? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to move large number of reports is by using some sort of deployment tool.
You can simply retrieve the metadata files of all reports, copy them in respective folder and deploy that folder again.

Here is an example:

[How to move reports from one folder to another massively?](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008quqIAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can move reports through the API. The [Reports and Dashboards REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_save_report.htm) supports a PATCH request that moves a given report to another folder, identified by Id. Unfortunately, a Report on Reports doesn't provide the Id, although it can be copied from the URL bar when viewing an individual report.

With the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_report.htm) you can pull down the reports' metadata and re-deploy them into a different folder (by changing their entries in the `<members>` XML entries in your `package.xml`), but I don't believe you can change the location of an existing report, so you'd have to a deletion and then a re-upload. This would be easiest done via a tool like Eclipse.